# Can results from a catch block be passed to methods inside the try block?

Tags: c#, error-handling, scope, try-catch, httpwebresponse

I have the following code in my program:

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response == null)
        return false;
    aDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream()); //Load the response into another object
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    //404's are caught and are saved as the response.
    //The reason being that 404's from this particular
    // website still provide relevant information that needs
    // extracting.
    response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
}
finally
{
    response.Close();
}
```

My question is: If a WebException is caught, will the response from `response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;` be passed to the `aDoc.Load()` method?

As an aside, I had this following code before moving more of it into the try-catch block. I figured adding a `finally` with `Close()` would be safer, but I'm still wondering if I should have changed anything at all in the first place.

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
}

if (response == null)
    return false;
aDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will need to isolate the correct block of code like you have done in your second example.

You can nest of course:

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;

try {
    try {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    } catch (WebException e) {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
    }

    if (response == null) return false;

    aDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
} finally {
    if (response != null) response.Close();
}
```

Comment: This will definitely work for me :). I have a weird fear of multiple nests which I blame for me not seeing this solution. Since you commented on my second code snippet, could you say if that code is "less safe" than the code you provided? Or, is there no tangible difference?

Comment: In your second snippet if aDoc.Load() throws an exception you will never reach response.Close(). However, response is disposable so it would probably cleanup eventually.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for your response and for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

No,

If a `WebException` was thrown, it has left the `try` block, and no further code in the `try` block will be executed, only what is in the `finally` block.

Comment: Can't give +1's yet, so I'll just add a comment saying thanks for your response :D

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no - since the code that passes the response to `aDoc.Load()` is the last statement, the exception can only have happened either on or above that line.

Assuming `aDoc.Load()` never throws WebException, then the answer is no

If `aDoc.Load()` throws WebException then the exception could come from that method - so technically `aDoc.Load()` could have been passed the result from the `GetResponse()` method and the exception could have been thrown inside `aDoc.Load()` - depends on `aDoc.Load()` implementation though

An exception stops code execution so once the exception is thrown, the next piece of code to be executed is that which is in the `catch` block (or any catch block further up the stack if there isn't one present) and then the `finally` is run

My assumption is that aDoc.Load() isn't any kind of web method (and is maybe your own class) so you should be best educated on whether that throws WebException, but the answer is probably 'no'

Comment: You're correct on your assumption. The Load() method is part of the HtmlAgilityPack which helps parse web pages. This particular method doesn't access the web.

Even if I wasn't thinking about that particular line throwing the exception, it's given me a little more insight into what happens during an exception. So, thanks for your response :)

Comment: I've clarified the answer a bit as I thought it was lacking in a little detail